# chmod to change permissions of specific user

Tags: chmod, chown

I have two users, user1 and user2. I also have a file in `/path/to/file`. user1 should be able to have read-write access, while user2 should only have read access.

I know that I can change permissions with `chmod u=r /path/to/file` to read-only, however this changes the permissions for everyone? When executing the command as user1 the access changes for user1 and user2 as well. I haven't found a option to specify a user. Is this something where I'd have to use the groups? Or `chown`? How would I go about doing this?

Is this also possible to do for a whole directory full of files? If there is a dir `/path/to/dir` that contains n files and m subdirs, to change the permissions of every file and every file in the subdirs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next solution:

- change the ownership of the file: `chown user1 /path/to/file`
- change permission for the owner, group and other: `chmod 644 /path/to/file`

This will give `rw` to `user1` and `r` to `user2`

For directories you must add `x` to give the option to the user to change in this directory:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/directory
```

Be careful with `-R` because this will change also the subdirectories

To automate the work you can use something like. Be very carefull for the start directory because those commands can change permissions of files you do not want to touch

```
find /path/to/file -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

for files

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

for directories

Comment: I just edited the question: is this possible for whole dirs as well? I just did `chown user1 ./` and `chmod -R 644 ./` and now I don't have any access to the dir, even as user1.

Comment: @Legatio, please check my edited answer

Comment: thanks now I can access the dir again. Is it possible to add x to the dir and subdirs but not the files in those dirs? I would want user2 to only read the files and not execute them.

Comment: @Legatio, yes, thats possible, see my edited answer

Comment: how would I use the 2 `find` commands for the concrete example I added to my question?

Comment: @Legatio, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

The traditional Unix permissions are quite coarse-grained, distinguishing only between owner (user), group and others, where a user (more precisely, a process) can belong to several groups. Most current Linux installations create a private group for each user, to isolate users a bit more among themselves (many legacy Unix systems had a catchall group `users` for all users, so if e.g. I made some of my files group readable/writeable, *everybody* could have a day with them).

You can set up a group to which only `user1` and `user2` belong, and use group permissions to get some of what you want, but it isn't at all perfect.

Modern Linux kernel/filesystems/tools handle  Access Control Lists (ACLs), see `acl(5)`. Using ACLs you get more fine grained control, i.e., say "`user1` has this exact permissions on object `foo`".